# Filtering a queryset issue in view django

Tags: python, django

I apologise in advance as im still new to django and I've inherited this projects.

i currently have this views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        location = request.GET.get('location', request.user.profile.location)
        users = User.objects.filter(profile__location=location) 
        print (users)
        matches = Match.objects.get_matches_with_percent(request.user)
        print (matches)
```

I get a list of users from matching app in "matches = " like this from the print (matches) `[[<User: lucy>, '79.00%'], [<User: newuser>, '70.71%'],......`

and i get a list of users from the "users =" like this from print (users) `[<User: jonsnow>, <User: newuser>]......`

how do i filter matches down to the users that come through, i tried adding a .filter(User=users) on the end of "matches =" however i got this error "'list' object has no attribute 'filter'".

I really hope this makes some sense i do apologise if I've explained my self very badly here, and thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What does `get_matches_with_percent` method do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension. They're fairly quick, execution time-wise. The following should do the trick:

```
matches = [match for match in matches if match[0] in users]
```

**OR**

```
user_ids = users.values_list('id', flat=True)
matches = [match for match in matches if match[0].id in user_ids]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!

Answer (score 1):

`get_matches_with_percent` is not a django method, but a custom method in your models manager. When searching the internet I assume that [this is your code](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/matchmaker-2/blob/master/src/matches/models.py#L85-L97), and specifically your method. It does not return a QuerySet but a regular list. You will have to update that method if you want to be able to filter the QuerySet instead.